# Javascript: How to Export a MIDI File?

Tags: javascript, midi

I am new to working with MIDI in my javascript code, and I would like to create an application that simply generates a MIDI file based on the user's input.  I have looked at using [MIDI.js](https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js), but I'm not sure if I need any of the library.  Ideally, I would like to be able to work with note values rather than hexadecimal MIDI codes... would I need to use the converter within `plugin.js`?

My current research has indicated that generated soundfonts are the suggested way to go; however, I would like to export/generate a MIDI file for use in a professional DAW.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for? Do you want to know how to generate a MIDI file in your own code? Questions asking to recommend or find a library are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: The former: how to generate a MIDI file using javascript.

Comment: Read the [specification](http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/midiformat.pdf) (PDF), write the appropriate code. What specific problem do you have with that?

Comment: Can you give a sample of the input you'd like to see and the output? It'd help me to see if there is something I know about that's already out there.

Comment: Looking here: https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js (the MIDI.js samples), there is a method, `MIDI.Player.loadFile(file, callback)` to load a MIDI file, but I cannot find one to save a MIDI file. (I found this SO while searching how to save a MIDI file based off a graphically defined loop)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a library I found called [MidiWriterJS](http://grimmdude.com/MidiWriterJS/docs/index.html).

It is very easy to use:

#### Step 1: Install

The easiest way to insall is to use [npm](http://npmjs.com).

```bash
$ npm install midi-writer-js
```

Then

```js
var MidiWriter = require('midi-writer-js');
```

#### Step 2: Create an array of tracks and add notes

```js
var tracks = [];
for(t of <your existing track array>){
    var notes = [];
    for(n of <your existing note array for the track>){
        notes.push(new MidiWriter.NoteEvent({pitch: <array of all notes in the chord>, duration: <how long the chord should last>});
    }
    var newTrack = new MidiWriter.Track();
    newTrack.addEvent(notes, function(event, index){ return {sequential: true}; });
    tracks.push(newTrack);
}
```

#### Step 3: Export the MIDI Data

```js
var writer = new MidiWriter.Writer(tracks);
writer.saveMIDI(<filename>);
```

Comment: The saveMIDI method is yet to be documented. https://github.com/grimmdude/MidiWriterJS/issues/54